# Sum of RVs divided by expectation converges to 1 in probability (with constraints on expectation, Var and Cov)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $\mu,\sigma,n_0>0$. Show that for every sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots$ with
$$
E(X_i)\geq\mu \\
Var(X_i)\leq\sigma^2<\infty \\
Cov(X_i,X_j)\leq0\quad \text{for} |i-j|>n_0
$$

for all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ it holds

$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\underbrace{P\left(\left|\frac{S_N-E[S_N]}{E[S_N]}\right|>\epsilon\right)}_{=:(*)}=0
$$

for all $\epsilon>0$ , where $S_N=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ .

I started with Chebyshev inequality but in the end I don't know how to get the right estimation:

$$
(*)\leq P\left( |S_N-E[S_N]|\ge\epsilon E[S_N]\right)\le\frac{Var(S_N)}{\epsilon^2 E[S_N]^2} \\
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^NVar(X_i)+2\sum_{i<j}Cov(X_i,X_j)}{\epsilon^2(\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^NE[X_i]}_{\ge N\mu})^2}\le\frac{N\sigma^2 +\ (?)}{\epsilon^2N^2\mu^2}
$$

where at $(?)$ I couldn't figure out an upper bound for these covariances that is not of order $N^2$, i.e. such that the fraction tends to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_{i,j}:=\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_i,X_j\right)$. Observe that by the condition in the third line of the opening post, 
$$
\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}c_{i,j}\leqslant \sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n, j-i\leqslant n_0}c_{i,j}
$$
and by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $c_{i,j}\leqslant \sigma^2$ hence 
$$\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}c_{i,j}\leqslant\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i+1\leqslant j\leqslant \min\left\{n,i+n_0\right\} }^n 1\leqslant\sigma^2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i+1\leqslant j\leqslant  i+n_0  }^n 1\leqslant \sigma^2n\cdot n_0. $$